# Is Hibernate deprecated?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This morning I was aboard a S-Bahn (German Subway) and I met a fellow student, who works for IBM. What he is doing there is Java EE optimization. I told him about my little project. And he recommended not to use 'oldschool' Hibernate. That's why my question is:

Is Hibernate deprecated? 
(In combination with Java EE/Web Development)

..or did he just prate..

Comment: Which alternative did he suggest?

Comment: Did we say what is deprecated about Hibernate? Using the proprietary API as opposed to JPA? Hibernate's implementation?

Comment: @Robert Even the proprietary API isn't deprecated anyway (and is used under the hoods).

Comment: @Pascal : I agree. I don't mind using the Hibernate API where it brings value over JPA. I'm just trying to figure out the original statement.

Comment: @Pascal : Hehe, I could not agree more.

Comment: Maybe the big companies don't use Hibernate any more because they don't want to become dependent to jboss?!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, Hibernate is not deprecated.

However, there's now [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) (Java Persistence API), which is a standard API for doing the things that Hibernate does.

Note that JPA is just an interface specification. You'll need something that implements JPA, and Hibernate is one of the implementations of JPA. Besides Hibernate, there are a few others such as EclipseLink (the official reference implementation for JPA) and Apache OpenJPA.

Comment: In my opinion I'd still stick with Hibernate (using annotations, as it's my preference over XML for persistence) as it has a lot of things which JPA hasn't, yet, personally I'll wait for JPA 2.0.

Comment: JPA also works with annotations, not necessarily with XML. JPA 2.0 has been out for a while, but not everything supports it yet. I'd choose JPA, unless there is some compelling reason to use plain Hibernate (for example features that you really need that are not available through JPA).

Comment: @Binary255: JPA 2.0 **is** there and the gap between JPA 2.0 and Hibernate is thin now.

Comment: Oh. I've been out of the loop, sorry. I've only used JPA 1.0 in the past and compared to Hibernate the latter won, even though the former was a standard. It's good if the standard has evolved though, I would use the standard too if I didn't find it lacking something vital to me.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate, apart from being an implementation of JPA, does provide a lot of extra advanced feature that JPA lacks of (extra syntax in query, QBC support etc).  Some of them are really useful and hard to find a workaround in JPA world (yet).  Without providing such features, it is hard to say JPA can "replace" Hibernate (hence, saying Hibernate being deprecating)

Comment: A *lot of extra advanced features* is not so true anymore with JPA 2.0. Yes, JPA 2.0 is still lacking some features such as Query By Example, custom user types,... but JPA 2.0 is a big improvement and makes the need for proprietary features rare.

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate is the JPA provider offered by JBoss, which is a Java EE server, so I doubt that Hibernate *as an implementation* is deprecated.

Perhaps he meant that using Hibernate within a Java EE server , bypassing the container-provider persistence, is deprecated and you should rely on our container for such services.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way that `Hibernate` is deprecated. There is the `JPA` which is a persistence specification and `Hibernate` implements it. Also `Hibernate` has its own advanced features that `JPA` does not have and that's why `Hibernate` is the main source of new features that are added to the `JPA` standard.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason why he may have suggested you against Hibernate is that for a small project, the overhead of understanding Hibernate can be quite significant.

Hibernate is *vast* to say the least. Though it can be used in a simple way, but to find that out too, you'll need to comprehend a whole lot more.

but be rest assured that Hibernate is NOT deprecated, or going to be any time in the distant future. it's just that if your ORM needs are modest, you might want to try other solutions like iBATIS

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said, it sounds like **he may have been referring to Hibernate xml mappings**, in contrast to using Hibernate annotations or JPA.  XML is most certainly old-school rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

JPA is only one way to do it. There's still Spring and all the other frameworks where Hibernate is well alive.